# PayPal module Prestashop (sandbox mode)

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I'm on a PrestaShop 1.2.x and I have PayPal and PayPal api modules, this is the only payment method.

Now, I'm testing it in the sandbox mode and I can pay using a developer tester account all right, but when I return to the shop an order with Error Payment is created!

Does anybody know what I can do to solve this?

This is the message from PayPal about the order:

> ```
> En 06-09-2012 16:47:06 desde Privado:
> Pago: Pending
> ```

Thanks! And sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 0):

Try again with `debug sandbox mode`, and then when in sandbox try all method testing (combobox method payment). If working correctly and in online mode still error.

You should modify paypal modul, create log payment to save txt file when trying sandbox method. You will see record data. maybe something wrong when submit data.